# iOS: [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]; makes my app to crash

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, ipad, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a UITableViewController, and I want to feed it with the content of a core data model.
However, when I fetch the content my app crashes. This is the init method (I pass a NSManagedObjectContext to it).

```
- (id)initInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

    if (self) {
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Document" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        request.predicate = nil;    
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"idDoc" 
                                                                                     ascending:YES]];
         /*
         NSError *error = nil;
         NSManagedObject *retrievedDocument = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] lastObject];
         NSLog(@"retrievedDocument %@", retrievedDocument);
         */

        NSFetchedResultsController *frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                                             initWithFetchRequest:request 
                                             managedObjectContext:context 
                                               sectionNameKeyPath:nil 
                                                        cacheName:@"CollectionCache"];

        self.fetchedResultsController = frc;
        [frc release];
        [request release];


        //HERE IT CRASHES
        NSError *error;
        [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];

        if (error) {
            // Update to handle the error appropriately.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            //exit(-1);  // Fail
        }

    }
    return self;
}
```

I'm sure the context is correctly passed because if I uncomment the commented snippet, the stored data are correctly printed.

My guess is that something is wrong with the fetchedResultsController.

thanks

Comment: What does the stacktrace and console say after the crash occured?

Comment: @Nick Weaver The console doesn't say anything. xCode highlight the instance     DisplayResutsTableViewController *resultsTableView = [[DisplayResutsTableViewController alloc] initInManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]; with the following message: "Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_..." and there is no way I can read the complete message but I guess it is about memory access.

Comment: @Patrick [Enable NSZombie](http://cocoa-nut.de/?p=16) for your active executable and see if the console output yields something new.

Comment: @Nick Weaver I've set it in my xCode4 (http://d.pr/vuye), and I've also tried to add the lines of code from your link, to see if it works. The BAD Memory Access error from their lines is still detected, but still my console doesn't say anything, wierd.

Comment: Hmm ok, let's try to cross out some things: how is the property fetchedResultsController declared?

Comment: @Nick Weaver     NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController; and then 
@property (retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

Comment: Just to be sure, if you remove `[frc release];` and `[request release];` does it still crash?

Comment: @Patrick verify if your sort descriptor is correct: is "idDoc" an NSNumber, or a NSString? Try commenting the line related to setting up the sort descriptor and see if it works.

Comment: @unforgiven well I comment out the line where I'm setting up sortDescriptor I get 'An instance of NSFetchedResultsController requires a fetch request with sort descriptors'. It is a NSString, I don't have a field with NSNumber.

Comment: @unforgiven I've also tried to change the field to NSNumber but it crashes anyway. So frustrating, I guess it is a really stupid bug.

Comment: @Nick Weaver and @unforgiven The error was due to the not initialized NSError error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception was not related to fetchedResultsController but due to the not initialized NSError

NSError *error = nil;

Comment: You're not using the API correctly. See [Handling Error Objects Returned from Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-SW1).

Answer (score 2):

The exception was related to your wrong use of `performFetch:`

It returns a BOOL that tells you the success of the fetch. If you get a NO back you are allowed to check the NSError object. Otherwise you must not touch it.

Probably all the methods that use &error should be used like this:

```
    NSError *error;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        // Update to handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        //exit(-1);  // Fail
    }
```